# How Can I Store a String in MIPS using Dynamic Memory?

Tags: memory, dynamic, assembly, stack, mips

Okay guys, basically the problem I'm having is this.

I've been assigned to write a MIPS program that stores a struct dynamically.

Basically, it stores an ID, a Year, a Title, and a Description
It's to be stored using a binary search tree.

If you've ever coded a stack in C++ you know what I'm talking about.
I've successfully stored the ID and Titles in memory dynamically,
but I'm having trouble storing the user-entered strings.

This is a complex question and there's not a lot of info that I've
been able to find online so props if you can help me out with this :)

Here is my memory setup:

$s5 - Stores Root Node

$s7 - Stores Size of Tree (Not Necessary)

Each New Item Contains a chunk of 344 bytes

The bytes are setup as such:

8 Bytes - [ID]

8 Bytes - [Year]

64 Bytes - [Title]

256 Bytes - [Description]

8 Bytes - [LastNodeAddress]

8 Bytes - [NextNodeAddress]

Here's the code and you may see the issue:

```
li $v0, 9           #allocate memory for new record
li $a0, 344         #enough memory for 2 addresses and all the data
syscall


move $s0, $v0           #hang onto the initial address of all our info

li $v0, 4           #prompt for ID
la $a0, addid
syscall

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall

sw $v0, 0($s0)          #store our ID into memory   Offset: 0

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add year
la $a0, addyear
syscall

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall

sw $v0, 4($s0)          #store year into our memory Offset: 4

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add title
la $a0, addtitle
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read title into titlebuffer
la $a0, titlebuffer
li $a1, 64
syscall

sw $a0, 8($s0)          #store title into our memory    Offset: 8

li $v0, 4           #prompt for add description
la $a0, adddescription
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read from input into descriptionbuffer
la $a0, descriptionbuffer
li $a1, 256
syscall

sw $a0, 72($s0)         #store description into our memory  Offset: 72

bne $s7, 0, setlocations    #if this isn't root node let's set the locations

add $s7, $s7, 1         #add 1 to the size of the records

move $s5, $s0           #store this address as root node for now
```

The problem is that all that's being stored is the address of the buffers.
The buffers are defined in my data section like this:

```
.data
titlebuffer: .space 64
descriptionbuffer: .space 256
```

What I end up with is just the addresses stored in the memory I allocated,
and I have no idea how to store strings into allocated memory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't bother defining your memory at the start of your program like I showed in the original question.

Instead, allocate it and read the values into the correct offsets of your dynamic memory.

Instead of `la $a0, descriptionbuffer`

Instead of `la $a0, titlebuffer`

Use:

`la $a0, 8($s0)`

`la $a0, 72($s0)`

Here I move the memory address into `$s0` using `move $s0, $v0` and read the values into the correct offsets.

to print you do the same thing!

Here is the working code:

```
li $v0, 9           #allocate memory for new record
li $a0, 344         #enough memory for 2 addresses and all the data
syscall

move $s0, $v0           #hang onto the initial address of all our info

li $v0, 8           #read our title into the allocated space
la $a0, 8($s0)          #Offset: 8
li $a1, 64
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read our description into the allocated space
la $a0, 72($s0)         #Offset: 72
li $a1, 256
syscall
```

In addition, you can find the final solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953839/1274820

**Edit: Well, after 10k views, I decided to add more info here so you don't have to search through later code**

Here's the full code to store 4 different pieces of data in memory:

```
li $v0, 9           #allocate memory for new record
li $a0, 344         #[334 = how much memory - in bytes]
syscall

move $s0, $v0       #store the address of our allocated memory in $s0

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall
sw $v0, 0($s0)      #store our ID into memory   Offset: 0

li $v0, 5           #enter integer
syscall
sw $v0, 4($s0)      #store year into our memory Offset: 4

li $v0, 8           #read our title into the allocated space
la $a0, 8($s0)      #Offset: 8
li $a1, 64
syscall

li $v0, 8           #read our description into the allocated space
la $a0, 72($s0)     #Offset: 72
li $a1, 256
syscall
```

That will store ID, Year, Title, and Description - the offset is where we place the data in the dynamic memory.

Imagine that I have a block of 334 bytes (like above):

`[            334             ]`

We store the `ID` an integer (4 bytes of data) at offset 0 like this:

`[(ID)        330             ]`

Then, we store the year next to it (at offset 4).

`[(ID)(YR)    326             ]`

And so on ...

To print it, do it like this:

```
li $v0, 1           #Print the ID stored at $s0     [Offset: 0]
lw $a0, 0($s0)
syscall
li $v0, 1           #Print the Year stored at $s0   [Offset: 4]
lw $a0, 4($s0)
syscall
li $v0, 4           #Print the Title stored at $s0  [Offset: 8]
la $a0, 8($s0)
syscall
li $v0, 4           #Print descript stored at $s0   [Offset: 72]
la $a0, 72($s0)
syscall
```