# Binary Search Tree MIPS confusion

Tags: binary, binary-search-tree, mips

I have a project where I need to create a binary search tree in MIPS. I have it well understood in C but MIPS is where I get lost. My professor has included this code to work with the inserting method. I am confused on the difference between addNodeToTree and addNode:

```
    # add a node to tree
    # 
    # input: $a0 the address of the tree
    #    $a1 the value you want to add to the tree

addNodeToTree :
    subu $sp, $sp, 4    # adjust the stack pointer 
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # save the return address on stack 
    subu $sp, $sp, 4    # adjust the stack pointer 
    sw $a0, 0($sp)      # save the parameter 

    lw $a0, 0($a0)      # addNode(bTree->root);
    jal addNode

    lw $a0, 0($sp)      # get the parameter 
    addu $sp, $sp, 4        # adjust the stack pointer 
    lw $ra, 0($sp)      # get the return address
    addu $sp, $sp, 4    # adjust the stack pointer 

    jr $ra


# please implement this method
#
# add a node to tree
# 
# input: $a0 the address of the root node
#    $a1 the value you want to add to the tree
#
# hint: you need to write a recursive call here

addNode :

    jr $ra                  # to return
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
[BInary tree project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953839/1274820)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given code addNodeToTree is where you do preparation before you actually insert a node to tree. In terms of c this can be represented as follows:

```
void addNodeToTree(struct BinaryTree btree, int newValue){
     struct Node root = btree->root;
     addNode(root, newValue);
}

void addNode(struct Node root, int newValue){
     //please implement this method
}
```

where in the struct BinaryTree address of root, current depth etc. can be held and in the struct Node; left child, right child and parent node etc. can be held.

The real task given here is to implement addNode where you have root's address on $a0 and newValue itself in $a1. So when somewhere in main or any other function calls addNodeToTree with binaryTree's address(not root's address) and a value, addNodeToTree can prepare arguments and call addNode function to do the real work.